# Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Hi I'm using Android Studio to generate a signed APK, when try to generate, I get this error:

```
Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: 
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc
```

Have read some posts related to differences between libraries and plugin versions, but don't know how to check this.

Any help, please?

Comment: I think your method count is more than 65k Try with multidex library. What is minimum api level you are using in gradle ?

Comment: I don't know, can't find the 'defaultConfig' parameters, if you are talking about this

Comment: Are you checking project gradle or app gradle ?

Comment: I added this line to both files "build.gradle" (Module: CordobaLib) and "build.gradle" (Module: myApp):
`multiDexEnabled true`

And then tried to compile again and get this error:
`Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class`